# dificuldade com acesso ao mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, conexão

estou tentando conectar remotamente a um mysql no google cloud, mas nao consigo. no google criei uma vm Ubuntu, ultima versao, esse é o meu ip,
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

esta pingando normalmente:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

configurei o firewall da seguinte forma:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

configurei no iptables:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

configurei tb o my.cnf:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

rodei o comando namp -sT -O localhst, a porta esta aberta:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estou há dois dias tentando uma conexão externa, mas sempre tenho o mesmo erro:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

internamente, por ssh, conecta normalmente, apenas conexão externa q nao dá certo.

Comment: Você precisa explicitar qual IP o servidor utilizará, senão ele só escutará no 127.0.0.1, no arquivo "my.cnf" uso o parâmetro "bind-address", coloque logo após a o "port".

Comment: devo colocar o ip interno? ou o externo, como o meu ip externo nao é fixo, o q devo colocar?

Comment: vc precisa liberar o acesso externo no my.cnf. Mudar linha
`bind-address = 127.0.0.1`
para
`#bind-address = 127.0.0.1`